# Update values in a cell based on other values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table called temptable and I have to update the 'quantity' for each 'cusip' based on the 'trantype' and 'tradedate'. The logic is sum(BUY)==sum(SELL), repeat the same logic when again a BUY appears after SELL. So, I came with an idea to randomly generate all BUY values and manipulate the SELL values based on them.

This is the table script and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE temptable(
TRANTYPE  VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL 
,CUSIP     VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
,TRADEDATE DATE  NOT NULL
,QUANTITY  INTEGER 
);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('BUY','XYZ003$03','2018-08-01',3517150);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('BUY','XYZ004$04','2018-08-01',2575357);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('BUY','XYZ102$02','2018-08-01',6523548);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('BUY','XYZ006$06','2018-08-02',9429433);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('BUY','XYZ006$06','2018-08-02',9240844);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('BUY','XYZ006$06','2018-08-02',9056027);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('BUY','XYZ007$07','2018-08-02',4266903);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('BUY','XYZ104$04','2018-08-02',6914360);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('BUY','XYZ004$04','2018-08-03',2523849);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('SELL','XYZ007$07','2018-08-08',NULL);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('BUY','XYZ007$07','2018-08-15',4097932);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('SELL','XYZ006$06','2018-09-04',NULL);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('SELL','XYZ102$02','2018-10-05',NULL);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('SELL','XYZ003$03','2018-10-18',NULL);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('SELL','XYZ003$03','2018-10-24',NULL);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('SELL','XYZ003$03','2018-10-26',NULL);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('SELL','XYZ003$03','2018-10-29',NULL);
INSERT INTO temptable(TRANTYPE,CUSIP,TRADEDATE,QUANTITY) VALUES ('SELL','XYZ007$07','2018-08-16',NULL);
```

This is what I’m trying to obtain:

Sample 1:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].temptable WHERE CUSIP ='SCD007$07';
```

Expexted results:

```
-- +----------+-----------+------------+----------+
-- | TRANTYPE |   CUSIP   | TRADEDATE  | QUANTITY |
-- +----------+-----------+------------+----------+
-- | BUY      | XYZ007$07 | 2018-08-02 |  4266903 |
-- | SELL     | XYZ007$07 | 2018-08-08 |  4266903 |
-- | BUY      | XYZ007$07 | 2018-08-15 |  4097932 |
-- | SELL     | XYZ007$07 | 2018-08-16 |  4097932 |
-- +----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Sample 2:

```
SELECT * FROM temptable WHERE CUSIP = 'SCD003$03';`
```

Expexted results:

```
-- +----------+-----------+------------+----------+
-- | TRANTYPE |   CUSIP   | TRADEDATE  | QUANTITY |
-- +----------+-----------+------------+----------+
-- | BUY      | XYZ003$03 | 2018-08-01 |  3517150 |
-- | SELL     | XYZ003$03 | 2018-10-18 |   879287 |
-- | SELL     | XYZ003$03 | 2018-10-24 |   879287 |
-- | SELL     | XYZ003$03 | 2018-10-26 |   879287 |
-- | SELL     | XYZ003$03 | 2018-10-29 |   879287 |
-- +----------+----------+------------+----------+
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
DECLARE @CUSIP VARCHAR(9) = 'XYZ02$02';
DECLARE @NO_SELL INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT_TRANSACTION
FROM [dbo].temptable
WHERE [CUSIP] = @CUSIP AND [TRANTYPE] = 'SELL'
GROUP BY [TRANTYPE],[CUSIP]);

UPDATE [dbo].temptable
SET QUANTITY = (SELECT SUM(QUANTITY)/@NO_SELL FROM [dbo].temptable WHERE [CUSIP] = @CUSIP AND [TRANTYPE] = 'BUY')
WHERE [CUSIP] = @CUSIP AND  [TRANTYPE] = 'SELL';
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You don't appear to have asked one.

Comment: you need to share what you have tried

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [start here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: Hello everyone, I just modified the question in suggested format. Someone, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to update the `quantity` of *sell* records (`trantype = 'SELL'`), and set it to the `quantity` of the preceeding *buy* (`trantype = 'BUY'`) of the same customer (`cusip`), where records are sorted by `tradedate`. When there are several sell records in between two buys, you want to evenly distribute the `quantity` of the preceeding buy over the sell records.

Here is a SQLServer 2017 query that produces the expected output. Basically, it self-`JOIN`s the buy records with the corresponding sale ; a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition is used to locate the relevant sale record (fist preceeding). Then, window function `COUNT(*) OVER(...)` is used to divide the quantity according to the number of consecutive sell record. The query also respects pre-existing sell quantities, if any.

```
SELECT 
    t.trantype, 
    t.cusip, 
    t.tradedate, 
    COALESCE(
        tbuy.quantity / COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t.cusip, tbuy.tradedate), 
        t.quantity
    ) quantity
FROM temptable t
LEFT JOIN temptable tbuy 
    ON  t.quantity IS NULL
    AND t.trantype = 'SELL'
    AND tbuy.trantype = 'BUY'
    AND tbuy.cusip = t.cusip
    AND tbuy.tradedate < t.tradedate
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM temptable tbuy1
        WHERE 
            tbuy1.trantype = 'BUY'
            AND tbuy1.cusip = t.cusip
            AND tbuy1.tradedate < t.tradedate
            AND tbuy1.tradedate > tbuy.tradedate
    )
ORDER BY t.cusip, t.tradedate, t.trantype
```

Now if you are looking to update the source table, you can turn the query to a CTE. The query can be simplified a bit, since it only needs to affect empty sell records.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 
    t.trantype, 
    t.cusip, 
    t.tradedate, 
    t.quantity,
    tbuy.quantity / COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t.cusip, tbuy.tradedate) new_quantity
FROM temptable t
LEFT JOIN temptable tbuy 
    ON  t.quantity IS NULL
    AND t.trantype = 'SELL'
    AND tbuy.trantype = 'BUY'
    AND tbuy.cusip = t.cusip
    AND tbuy.tradedate < t.tradedate
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM temptable tbuy1
        WHERE 
            tbuy1.trantype = 'BUY'
            AND tbuy1.cusip = t.cusip
            AND tbuy1.tradedate < t.tradedate
            AND tbuy1.tradedate > tbuy.tradedate
    )
)
UPDATE cte 
SET quantity = new_quantity 
WHERE trantype = 'SELL' AND quantity IS NULL
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=60edf7d5bd30a951a0c3e92234e7c4a4)**:

```
TRANTYPE | CUSIP     | TRADEDATE           | QUANTITY
:------- | :-------- | :------------------ | -------:
BUY      | SCD003$03 | 01/08/2018 00:00:00 |  3517150
SELL     | SCD003$03 | 18/10/2018 00:00:00 |   879287
SELL     | SCD003$03 | 24/10/2018 00:00:00 |   879287
SELL     | SCD003$03 | 26/10/2018 00:00:00 |   879287
SELL     | SCD003$03 | 29/10/2018 00:00:00 |   879287
BUY      | SCD004$04 | 01/08/2018 00:00:00 |  2575357
BUY      | SCD004$04 | 03/08/2018 00:00:00 |  2523849
BUY      | SCD006$06 | 02/08/2018 00:00:00 |  9429433
BUY      | SCD006$06 | 03/08/2018 00:00:00 |  9240844
BUY      | SCD006$06 | 04/08/2018 00:00:00 |  9056027
SELL     | SCD006$06 | 04/09/2018 00:00:00 |  9056027
BUY      | SCD007$07 | 02/08/2018 00:00:00 |  4266903
SELL     | SCD007$07 | 08/08/2018 00:00:00 |  4266903
BUY      | SCD007$07 | 15/08/2018 00:00:00 |  4097932
SELL     | SCD007$07 | 16/08/2018 00:00:00 |  4097932
BUY      | SCD102$02 | 01/08/2018 00:00:00 |  6523548
SELL     | SCD102$02 | 05/10/2018 00:00:00 |  6523548
BUY      | SCD104$04 | 02/08/2018 00:00:00 |  6914360
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really works well for me. Except there is an exception for one cusip.